# Edit Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog button text

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I want to use `Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog` but I need to edit the button's text, is it optional ? if yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

The previous version [Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/jj602956(v=crm.8)#BKMK_confirmDialog) does not have an option to customize the button label text. And its [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility#deprecated-methods) too.

Based on your CRM 2016 version - we don't have any supported way to achieve it.

Whereas the latest version [Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openconfirmdialog) is having that option to customize the button label text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Further to **@Arun Vinoth's** answer, the JS to edit the button's text would look similar to:

```
const confirmStrings = {
  cancelButtonLabel: "Cancel this change"    // Cancel button text
  confirmButtonLabel: "Confirm this change"  // Confirm button text   
};
Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings).then(...
```

You didn't specify which button you wish to edit, so both are included.